# Use a base class' function with inherited classes values

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is there any way to call a parent's function from a child class but within the function use data from the child instead of the parent eg.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base{

public:
    int i=10;

    virtual void print(){
        printf("%i", i );
    }

};


class Derived : public Base {

public:
    int i = 20;

    void print(){
        Base::print();
    }

};

int main (){

    Derived I;
    I.print();    

}
```

So I want this to print 20 instead of 10 basically.

EDIT ::::::::::::

What I am actually trying to do is use a base class that defines multiple functions

```
    virtual int OnExecute();

    virtual bool OnInit();

    virtual void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);

    virtual void OnLoop();

    virtual void OnRender();

    virtual void OnCleanUp();
```

Then have a derived class overload all of those functions exept OnExectue() which looks like this

```
 if (OnInit() == 0 ){
    return -1;
    }

    SDL_Event Event;
    while (isRunning){
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&Event)){
                    OnEvent(&Event);
            }
            OnLoop();
            OnRender();
    }

OnCleanUp();
```

So is there a more simplistic way where i won't be having to define 5 extra functions to pass function pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dynamic_cast , Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class Derived;

class Base{
    public:
    int i=10;

    virtual void print();
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int i = 20;
    void print(){
        Base::print();
    }

};

void Base::print(){
    Derived* p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this);                                                                                                                               
    if(p) {
        //derived
        printf("%i\n", p->i);
    }else{
        //base
        printf("%i\n", i);
    }
}

int main (){

    Derived I;
    I.print();    

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make the use of Base::print() unusable to a Base object though?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you provide access to the data through a virtual member function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base{

public:
    int i=10;

    virtual void print(){
        printf("%i", this->getI() );
    }

    virtual int getI()
    {
       return i;
    }

};


class Derived : public Base {

public:
    int i = 20;

    void print(){
        Base::print();
    }

    virtual int getI()
    {
       return i;
    }
};

int main (){

    Derived I;
    I.print();    

}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of implementing `Derived::print()` only to call `Base::print()`.

Comment: You may want to print more data in `Derived::print()`.